# Ubuntu 18 Network is Unreachable, Can't Ping DNS

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have a DO droplet running and after resizing I can't connect to the internet..I emailed them but they are taking days to respond. At first the interface changed from eth0 to ens3 and I managed to change it back:

`ifconfig -a`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK7ea.png

`/etc/network/interfaces`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O42ZO.png

`ip addr`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzaV4.png

Nameservers are set to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in resolv.conf. I've spent days trying to fix this with no avail.

Sorry, can't copy and paste from console in browser so have to screenshot.

`ping 8.8.8.8`: connect: Network is unreachable

`ping google.com`: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: You need to make the `eth0` interface up. Run `ip link set dev eth0 up`.

Comment: You might not be able to copy and paste, but you could at least transcribe the information. What does `ifconfig eth0 up` do if anything? At the moment the eth0 interface is down but it has been up in the past as there are both sent and received data packets. Once you have the interface up, the next thing we need to see is the output of `ip route`.

Comment: I ran both commands and this is what ip route shows: https://i.imgur.com/erC3lc2.png
and route -n
https://i.imgur.com/0qotCW9.png. Still can't connect to SSH

Comment: `207.154.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 207.154.195.80`

`207.154.192.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 207.154.195.80`

Comment: Not being able to ssh at this stage is expected. Now run `ip route add default via 207.154.192.1 dev eth0`.

Comment: Wow that worked, thanks! Looks like it was the gateway that was the issue? If you want to make it an answer I can mark as correct